# Elasticsearch--reindexing to the same index name

Tags: elasticsearch, reindex

I have several old indices which I'd like to change mapping of. Now I need to transform old mapping into new ones. I've been reading on stackoverflow like

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371237/reindexing-elastic-search-via-bulk-api-scan-and-scroll#)

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851044/is-there-a-smarter-way-to-reindex-elasticsearch)

[and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007646/how-to-reindex-elasticsearch-quickly)

But I don't think they're the exact answer to my question.

Many of those use a different index name, so operation is easier that way, but due to the setup, we use a more crude way of curl-ing the data, which requires the exact index name.

Now my question is: what's a good way to reindex an old index (or several indices) to new one

ex.

my current address would be 'http://address-to-server:port/cluster-name/index-name'

I want to be able to reindex the old data so that when i `curl -XGET 'http://address-to-server:port/cluster-name/index-name'` it'll give the the old data in new mapping (some additional fields, some modified)

Comment: You can use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump

Comment: but will this be able to handle a modification of fields? Say in old index mapping I have `field1 <type:float>` and the new mapping will have `field1<type:integer>`. Will it cause any error?

Comment: This is an import/export tool. If your mapping to data is broken - no tool can fix it...

Answer (score 1):

As my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34922287/2134604) you can use reindexing plugins to perform the mapping change actions

https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-reindexing

And also make sure that your new mapping is valid and will adopt your old data by checking sample input data

Answer (score 1):

Following method can be used to re-index the data.

1. Transfer data from original index to some dummy index. You can use below  command

   `elasticsearch-reindex -f "http://localhost:9200/original_index/type/" -t "http://localhost:9200/dummy_index/type/"`

   This command is to be used in terminal.
2. Delete the original index.
   `DELETE /original_index`
3. Create the index with same name as original index and with changed mapping.
4. Move the data back from dummy index to original index

   `elasticsearch-reindex -f "http://localhost:9200/dummy_index/type/" -t "http://localhost:9200/original_index/type/"`

THis way you can restore your data with new mappings.

**NOTE: You need to install npm plugin for this**.

Read [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-reindex)  to install `elasticsearch-reindex` command.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if I created the mapping just before the with reindex after delete the original index, should I have to use the again create desire mapping to back data from dummy index to original index??

Comment: Instead of step 3 and 4, just create an alias (with the original index name) to the new index. So no need to move data back.

Comment: This is very hard to pull off in production, what if after the transfer of data to the `dummy_index` is finished, there is a new data in the `original_index`. This data is now lost forever.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking to run reindex script to update the same index. Basically "reindexing to the same index" is an "update by query" (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html). You can use the same `script` clause as with reindex and apply it to a query result

Comment: at the time when I asked this, our version of ES was still on 1.x, which doesn't have update-by-query or delete-by-query functions. Gotta say, adding these functions make things a lot simpler

Comment: It is not the same. You can't change the _id using update by query.

Comment: Update by query will not allow you to change existing mappings. For that you need a new index.