# Elasticsearch: reindex and preserve the index name (without alias)

Tags: elasticsearch

from [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html):

> The most basic form of _reindex just copies documents from one index
>   to another. This will copy documents from the twitter index into the
>   new_twitter index

```
POST /_reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "twitter"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_twitter"
  }
}
```

but i don't want a index with a new name... how preserve the index name (without alias)?

Comment: Why do you want to re-index the same data? to update the mapping?

Comment: @Henrik yes... i have update index settings (analyzer)

Comment: You could index the data into a temporary index and then re-create the original index as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232606/elasticsearch-reindexing-to-the-same-index-name). Aliases is the recommended way to go.